# $("#id").scrollTop() returns null

Tags: jquery, html, web, scrolltop

I am trying to get the position of a coulpe  in my html page using the scrollTop() method in order to compare it with the position of the user, but it only returns null. Here is the code:

```
<div id="div1" class="transition">
    <img src="bg1.jpg"/>
</div>

<div id="div2" class="transition">
    <img src="bg2.jpg"/>
</div>
```

and the javascript:

```
var t1 = $('#div1').scrollTop();
var t2 = $('#div2').scrollTop();

console.log(t1 + " " + t2);
```

and it prints t1 and t2 = null.
Can you see where the problem is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `div`s don't have scrollbars (I'm assuming), so they naturally can't be scrolled.

If you want to find the position you need to scroll to so that they are at the top, try:

```
$('#id').offset().top
```

[(jQuery docs)](http://api.jquery.com/offset/)

Here's a working demo:

---

```js
var txt = $('#div1').offset().top + ' ' + $('#div2').offset().top;

document.getElementById('output').appendChild(document.createTextNode(txt));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='div1'>
  This is some stuff
</div>

<div id='div2'>
  More stuff
</div>

<div id='output'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks that's exaclty what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

use `.position().top` to get the position on the page:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k9dy6ewc/)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the whole thing in a document ready enclosure. Your javascript may be running before the dom has completed loading.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var t1 = $('#div1').scrollTop();
    var t2 = $('#div2').scrollTop();
    console.log(t1 + " " + t2);
});
```

Comment: This solution returns me 0. Maybe I miss-used the scrollTop() function. Thanks for answering.